# Issues when using my jar file which connects to database

Tags: jar

I  have created a jar file(sms.jar) which uses derby database and I have included it inside one of my projects (CommunicationProject) , I am using wildfly-8.0.0.Final to deploy my project (CommunicationProject) , as well as hibernate I am using derby in sms.jar and I am using mysql in CommunicationProject But i have following issues:

***Issue 1.*** I am always getting this log i really dont know whether it is just info or error

```
13:12:25,154 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2) Database 'smsDB' not created, connection made to existing database instead.: java.sql.SQLWarning: Database 'smsDB' not created, connection made to existing database instead.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.SQLWarningFactory.newSQLWarning(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
13:12:25,154 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2) Database 'smsDB' not created, connection made to existing database instead.: java.sql.SQLWarning: Database 'smsDB' not created, connection made to existing database instead.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.SQLWarningFactory.newSQLWarning(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
```

***Issue 2.*** Whenever i redeploy the application(CommunicationProject) on wildfly(the below error wont be generated in the first deploy after restarting/starting the wildfly) I got the following error

```
Location -> null, identityToken -> z8kfsx96zrszy08gkk4x|4b5c772, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
13:10:46,522 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-5) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@7440f05c -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
13:10:46,527 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner] (Timer-5) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@7440f05c -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6e703963 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@9c7cb3a (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1bef51da (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@7ce6cd89
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@14c01d6f
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main]
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main]
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
    Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main]
        java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(Native Method)
        org.apache.derby.impl.io.DirRandomAccessFile.sync(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
        java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)


13:10:59,542 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1bef51da -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: : java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'smsDB' with class loader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.CommunicationProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'smsDB' with class loader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.CommunicationProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/techbrainless/smsDB.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    ... 14 more

13:10:59,552 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (default task-9) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
13:10:59,560 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-9) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
13:10:59,565 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect] (default task-9) HHH000430: The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead
13:10:59,571 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (default task-9) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
13:10:59,578 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (default task-9) HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
13:10:59,581 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (default task-9) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:10:59,744 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (default task-9) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
13:10:59,931 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@9c7cb3a -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: : java.sql.SQLException: Database 'smsDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: Database 'smsDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    ... 19 more

13:10:59,932 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6e703963 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: : java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'smsDB', see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547) [c3p0-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
Caused by: ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'smsDB', see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: ERROR XBM0J: Directory /home/techbrainless/smsDB already exists.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source) [derby-10.11.1.1.jar:]
    ... 14 more


13:11:00,226 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (default task-9) HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

I have checked the port of derby whether it is opened or closed but I found no port number 1527 is opened , to overcome such issue i need to restart the wildfly which is not right.

***Issue 3.*** I have set the hibernate confiugration (inside jar file) 
<`property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` 
if I change it to

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

I need to create it the database manaully , my requirements is to create the database (sms.jar file should create the database) only in the first deploy time of the main application(application which uses the jar file which is CommunicationProject) and preserve the data inside smsDB database even if the the application(CommunicationProject) deployed for second , third ...etc times. or even if the wildfly server restarted.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:derby:smsDB;create=true
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```